# Problems in implementing signal R in my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I need to implement signal R in my asp.net project for sending notifications to employees.But I am facing the problem of owinstartup .I am getting error like this:

```
   The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- The given type or method 'Notify' was not found. Try specifying the Assembly.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- The given type or method 'Notify' was not found. Try specifying the Assembly.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.
```

my sartup class is like this:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup("Notify",typeof(CRMWeb.Startup))]
namespace CRMWeb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I have added this line to my appsetting in my web.config

```
 <add key="owin:appStartup" value="Notify" />
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the following `<addkey="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />` in your `web.config`?

Comment: Got the solution needed to remove name space CRMWeb from all places.Thx Izzy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to "Notify" at OwinStartup assembly. Just add startup class that documented from microsoft.

try this:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(CRMWeb.Startup))]

namespace CRMWeb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A little explanation of your solution would be helpful.